# Angular UI Google Maps Clustering: Disappearance and Flashing

Tags: google-maps-markers, markerclusterer, angular-google-maps

I have run into some pretty bad UX problems while developing with angular google maps and am looking for advice on the best way to proceed.

Relevant template:

```
    <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="options" bounds="map.bounds">
    <ui-gmap-markers doCluster="true" models="randomMarkers" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'">
    </ui-gmap-markers>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/mZvN6wCT9LCl1DWGojZD?p=preview

Two problems, both related to clustering:

First, on any sort of map event, most annoyingly drag, the clusters blink as they repaint, even if the cluster did not change position.

Second, the clusters disappear when they fall off the visible section of the map, which is probably good for performance but more of a UI pain if you're dealing with maps at a high zoom level, where things are in and out of the map's view all the time.

These issues are not apparent at the markercluster demo page:
http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0/examples/advanced_example.html

How have you addressed these issues? I've looked through the API's for both angular google maps and markerclustererplus, but to no avail.

I was under the assumption that the clusterer would just figure out which points belonged together, then make a marker that symbolized that collection. However it seems that the clusters behave so differently than markers (eg. the above issues) that this can't be the case.